# Android doesn't handle state change on Modal

Tags: android, react-native, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I'm coding a React-Native app and I'm having a weird issue, is not my first app so I don't know what's going on. I have a really simple modal, when it opens, it shows a message and a button to close it. When I press the button the visible state is changed to false, so on iOS the Modal leaves, but on Android, the app gets blocked after changing state and the Modal stays. Do you know what's going on? Am I missing something? Here is my code:

```
<Modal
    animationType={'fade'}
    transparent
    visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
    onRequestClose={this._hideModal}
>
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
         <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>Tip</Text>
         <Text style={styles.modalHint}>You can swipe up to dismiss an open item.</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight  
                underlayColor={'transparent'} 
                onPress={this._hideModal}
            >
                <View style={styles.buttonModal}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonModalText}>Got it!</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
</View>
```

The modal is shown on ComponentDidMount using a simple state change: `this.setState({isModalVisible: true});` and the _hideModal function is another simple state change: `this.setState({isModalVisible: false});`

> "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
>       "react-native": "0.47.1"

Comment: maybe try onPress={()=>{this._hideModal()}} ?

Comment: Oh, i forgot to say that the method is already binded, and since it's working on iOS it "should" work on Android `_hideModal = () => {
     this.setState({isModalVisible: false});
   }`